# Linear Regression - How to remove features behaves Heteroscedastic?

Tags: regression, outliers, heteroscedasticity

I'm making a model with 5 features (Paths, PathSegs, Polygons, Scalar Instances, and Standard Vias), and the output is memory consumption.

Essentially using these 5 features, I can predict how much memory consumption I will use.

Here is a diagram of the features vs memory usage.

[image]

Some features seems to be Heteroscedastic, especially Scalar Instances and Standard Vias.

If I trained a model (linear regression), and then plotted the output with the scalar instances, I would get something like this.

[image]

The problem is with the big jump when the Scalar instances are low. I imagine that when the features are small, then the memory consumption would also be small as well, then gradually increase.

I've tried a few different approaches with different models:

[image: enter code here]

And all of them have the same issues. So I'm thinking if I threw away Standard Vias, and Pathsegs, which has a big jump at low numbers, then I would get a more stable model. However, is there are systematic way of doing this?

Comment: You said you are using linear regression? These pictures don't look like linear models to me... can you clarify what model you are using?

Comment: I trained the model on all features, and not independently.

Comment: Ah, okay. In that case, its not clear to me that you have a problem... in those cases where you have high memory usage but low scaler instances, does one of the other features have a high value?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "heteroscedastic" feature?  Your use of this word does not seem to comport with its usual meaning.

Comment: @whuber, Sorry if I misunderstood it's meaning, I'm pretty new with the regression. It seems that the data spreads out with increasing value. I guess the problem falls under outliers?

Comment: @roundsquare Yes, that's the problem. It looks like a few features has this issue, and some features does not look like it can be fitted with linear regression, for example Pathsegs. Is there a way to correctly identify them and removing them from training (the whole feature)? Because I think I can look at them, and remove them manually, but I was wondering if there's a mathematical way of doing so.

Comment: @user1157751 I don't think you have a problem (or, if you do, I don't see it). You have an equation of the form $y = m_1 \times x_1 + ... + m_1 \times x_5 + c$. You shouldn't necessarily expect that when you graph $y$ against $x_1$ (or any other $x_i$) you get a line or even something that moves gradually upwards because there are interactions with other variables. Indeed, this is the whole point of doing multiple regression.

Comment: @roundsquare Thanks for your input! Can I say that I have a problem of outliers? There are some points that lie far away from the "majority" of points.

Comment: @roundsquare There is also features, for example Pathsegs that does not look like there's a linear correlation, and if I can mathematically detect them and remove it?

Comment: @user1157751 (1) you may or may not have outliers, but its not clear that any potential outliers are creating problems; (2) Looking at the graph, there doesn't seem to be much connection between pathsegs and memory usage, but this is not necessarily a problem. When you run your linear regression, the coefficient for pathsegs will be small so it should be okay. Why do you think Pathsegs should be removed?

Comment: @roundsquare I think it doesn't have any correlation with memory usage. I'm trying to prevent the model jumping up and down when features are small. It looks like my option is 1. Determine if I have outliers, and remove them, and 2. Increase model bias?

Comment: @user1157751 if you build an accurate model, it may have high memory usage when one feature is small because a different feature is large. This is a good thing. If you try to stop it from doing this, you will lose model accuracy.

Comment: @roundsquare Alright, it looks like I should NOT fiddle with the parameters to increase bias (ridge, lasso, etc). Do you want to summarize and answer the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Summarizing from our conversation in the comments to your question).

Looking at the graphs, there is no apparent issue. You ran multiple regression and got an equation of the form: $y = \sum{m_i \times x_i} + c$. Afterwards, you are plotting $y$ against $x_i$ for a single $i$ so it isn't surprising that what you get (a) is not a line; and (b) is not even strictly increasing. The reason is that other $x$'s affect $y$. So, for example, when scaler instances is low, perhaps standard vias is high. As such, given with what know, there doesn't appear to be a problem with the graphs.

As for removing variables, there is no apparent reason to do at the moment. Its possible that some of  your features don't have much of an effect on memory usage but that's okay since the coefficients for this variables will be small.

By the way, if you do want to have a graph that shows *just* the effect of one feature (e.g. scaler instances) on memory usage, you can do this by holding the other features constant. Of course, the resulting line won't necessarily match up with the points in your data set, but that's okay because in those points, the other features are *not* being held constant.